# slurm, как задать что б job был распараллелен на все ядра узла

Tags: cluster

Есть вариант как то задать параметр --ntasks-per-node (использую в компании с параметром -N) так, что бы планировщик занимал все ядра на узле (если заранее не известно это количество)?

пробовал 0 и -1- не работает